# ASP.NET Call javascript function on enter key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, key, enter

I have an ASP.NET page with some text boxes meant for searching purpose. Now I want to invoke a javascript function which is already written, when the user press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key. I am having jQuery in my page.

Any easy ways to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#someid').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        SomeFunctionName();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the `onkeydown` attribute to the text box and apply the function like this example.

```js
function TextName_OnKeyDown(e)
{  
    var keynum;     
    if(window.event) // IE    
    {
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    }
    else if(e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
    {
        keynum = e.which;
    } 
  
    document.getElementById("keynum").innerHTML = keynum;
     
    if (keynum == 13) 
    {
        document.getElementById("keynum").innerHTML += " SearchByName();";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" ID="TextName" onkeydown="javascript:TextName_OnKeyDown(event)">
<p id="keynum"></p>
```